# Discord.js/ROBLOX API Endpoint issue returning "Typeerror: json.data is not iterable"

Tags: discord.js, roblox

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./config.json');
const token = config.token;
const globalprefix = config.prefix;
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

client.once('Ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!')
});

function EmbedMaker(GroupRank, Username) {
    const FunctionEmbedMessager = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(Username + "'s NUSA Role")
        .setField('NUSA Role', GroupRank, false);
  return FunctionEmbedMessager;
};

function GetUserIdFromUsername(Username) {
    (async () => {
        const json = await fetch("https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username=" + Username)
        .then((res) => res.json());
        for (const info of json.data) {
        return info.Id
        }
    })();
};

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (!msg.content.startsWith(globalprefix) || msg.author.bot) return;

    const args = msg.content.slice(globalprefix.length).trim().split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'checknusarole') {
        if (!args[0]) { msg.channel.send('**You did not specify a username to check the NUSA role of.**')}
        
        (async () => {
            const json = await fetch("https://groups.roblox.com/v2/users/" + GetUserIdFromUsername(args[0]) + "/groups/roles")
              .then((res) => res.json())
        .catch(() => false);
      if (!json.data) {return}
            for (const info of json.data) {
       
              if (info.group === 758071) {
          console.log('its nusa')
                  const ReturnedEmbed = EmbedMaker(info.group.role.name, args[0])
          msg.channel.send(ReturnedEmbed)
              }
            }
          })();
        
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

Basically, the above code is supposed to send a request to that url resulting in a JSON response, whenever I run this code, it will say "Type Error: JSON.data is not iterable", I have tried putting the catch, breaking the for in loop, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error said, `json.data is not iterable`. If I’m correct, you should put this in your `.then()` instead of after it. Here is how you should do it. Also, if `res.json()` is not an array or map (and I think it would be an object), use `for…in` instead.

```js
            const json = await fetch("https://groups.roblox.com/v2/users/" + GetUserIdFromUsername(args[0]) + "/groups/roles")
              .then((res) => { 
      const json = res.json()
       
      if (!json.data) {return}
            for (const info of json.data) {
       
              if (info.group === 758071) {
          console.log('its nusa')
                  const ReturnedEmbed = EmbedMaker(info.group.role.name, args[0])
          msg.channel.send(ReturnedEmbed)
              }
}
            })
```